# Python3 datetime module strange behavior

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timedelta

I came across a strange behavior of the *datetime module* of Python3: I calculate the difference between the dates "date" and "mon", and then add to the "date" first the resulting difference as it is, and then add to the "date" the resulting difference converted into seconds.
But for some reason, the dates are different, although they should be the same. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
date=datetime.datetime(2021,9,4,13,00)
mon=datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 6, 0, 0)
delta=mon-date
print(date+delta)
print(date+datetime.timedelta(seconds=(delta).seconds))
```

result:

> 2021-09-06 00:00:00

> 2021-09-05 00:00:00

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode Not exactly sure, the OP isn't so clear

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode I read it again, `total_seconds` is required

Comment: @U12-Forward, in this question the problem is they use `seconds`, instead of `total_seconds()`

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode Oh and yeah buran just posted that

Comment: @buran yeah was ready to answer, just saw your answer

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

`datetime.timedelta.seconds` attribute does not represent the total number of seconds in the period. There is `datetime.timedelta.total_seconds()` method for for that.

```
import datetime
date=datetime.datetime(2021,9,4,13,00)
mon=datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 6, 0, 0)
delta=mon-date
print(delta, delta.seconds)
print(delta == datetime.timedelta(seconds=delta.seconds))
print(date+delta)
print(date+datetime.timedelta(seconds=delta.total_seconds()))
```

output

```
1 day, 11:00:00 39600
False
2021-09-06 00:00:00
2021-09-06 00:00:00
```

As stated [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.resolution) the `timedelta.seconds` attribute is seconds between 0 and 86399 inclusive.